# Draw an elliptical or circular arc using polyline path in SVG

Tags: svg, polyline, catia

I am exporting a 2D profile containing elleptical/circular arcs from CATIA V5 into a SVG file. Paths for for arcs are represented as a polylines in SVG. This is causing problems while calculating properties of arcs in SVG. Please suggest if there is a way to fit an elliptical/circular arc for a given ployline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a question that would be better suited for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Paul, Posted it there.